# Angular Data table not displaying the data in the table

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I am building an application using Angular 12. In this application I have used angular-data table referring the its official documentation for sorting, pagination and filter, but I am getting an error.

Error: **Type 'import("C:/Project/Web Development/angulardatatables/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subject").Subject' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Project/Web Development/angulardatatables/node_modules/angular-datatables/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subject").Subject'.**

**Documentation Link:** http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way

**Below are the code files for better understanding**

**app.component.html**

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date & Time</th>
      <th>Point Name</th>
      <th>Data Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let group of data">
      <td>{{group.dated}}</td>
      <td>{{group.pointName}}</td>
      <td>{{group.dataName}}</td>
      <td>{{group.status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angulardatatables';

  alertArray: any = [];

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {

  }

  public data: any[] = [];
  /* dtOptions: any = {}; */
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  // We use this trigger because fetching the list of persons can be quite long,
  // thus we ensure the data is fetched before rendering
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnInit() {

    this.appService.getAlarmsHistory().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.data = response.alertResponses;
      // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // Do not forget to unsubscribe the event
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**Images**

[[image: error in [dtTrigger] in HTML1]

**any solution please ?**

Comment: Looks like there is different version od `rxjs` installed than `angulardatatables` requires. That may result in installing separate rxjs version under angulardatatables

Comment: Tomas Chabada: any solution in this case ? The problem is it is showing error in [dtTrigger] in html code

Comment: Yes, because it tries to bind `Subject` with value that comes from different rxjs package/version

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that `angulardatatables` was not installed as it should. This may be caused by different versions of `rxjs` library: one referenced by your project and other referenced by `angulardatatables`.

Check both versions, if they are different, than either `angulardatatables` or `rxjs` package should be updated/downgraded to the same version.

If the versions match and for some another reason this happened than you can issue a `npm dedupe` command that will flatten `node_modules` directories

You can also try to remove the `rxjs` package from the project and reinstall `angulardatatables` again. Then there won't be any reason for versions conflict and `angulardatatables` should be able to install dependent `rxjs` in a right place.

Comment: Tomas Chabada: uninstalled and reinstalled rxjs and angulardatatables but it is still showing error for [dtTrigger]

Comment: @MohitKumarSharma once you uninstall `rxjs` then do not install it again. `angulardatatables`  should install it, because it depends on it

Comment: Tomas Chabada: Uninstalled angulardatatables and then reinstalled angulardatatables  but no luck.

Comment: @MohitKumarSharma rxjs uninstall => tables uninstall => tables install, like this?

Comment: Tomas Chabada: yes, the same way you mentioned

Comment: Have you tries to issue `npm dedupe` command?

Comment: Tomas Chabada: yes I did